# When to stop looking for closed-form solutions?

Tags: soft-question, exponential-function, closed-form, lambert-w, transcendental-equations

I have the following equation which is simplified from another relatively long equation.
$$
xe^{-x}= c (\frac{x}{c})^{-x}
$$
Here Lambert W function doesn't help since you still get $x$ inside the Lambert W.

I know that I can use numerical methods to find the interception(s) of these two lines. But in general, I wonder at what point we can realize that there's no hope of finding the closed-form solution and we should stop looking for it.

Comment: You want $c$ in terms of $x$? or $x$ in terms of $c$?

Comment: Oh sorry, I want x in terms of c, $x = f(c)$. But $ c = g(x)$ would also be helpful. I have to look at it.

Comment: $x^{1+x}e^{-x}=c^{1+x}$

Answer (score 5):

Assume that both $x$ and $c$ are positive. So, as @user619894 commented
$$x^{1+x}e^{-x}=c^{1+x} \quad \implies \quad c=x \,e^{-\frac{x}{x+1}}\tag 1$$

$$\frac{x}{x+1}=y\quad \implies \quad c=\frac{e^{-y} \,y}{1-y}\quad \implies \quad \color{red}{e^{-y}=c \,\frac {1-y}y}$$
which has an explicit solution in terms  of the [generalized Lambert function](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999) (have a look at equation $(4)$).

This being said, if it is to have obtained a closed form expression, from a practical point of view, it is not very useful. However, if we consider the case of large values of  $x$ and $c$, we can write

$$x \,e^{-\frac{x}{x+1}}=\frac 1e \Big[x+1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac {a_n}{(n+1)! \,x^n}\Big]$$ The coefficient form sequence $A111884$ in $OEIS$.

Truncated to some order and using series reversion (with $t=e\,c$)
$$x=t-1+\frac{1}{2 t}+\frac{1}{3 t^2}-\frac{1}{8 t^3}-\frac{7}{15
   t^4}-\frac{31}{144 t^5}+\frac{19}{35 t^6}+\frac{4927}{5760
   t^7}-\frac{563}{2835 t^8}+O\left(\frac{1}{t^9}\right)$$

Using the above terms for $c=10$ gives the estimate
$x=\color{red}{26.20165628306}409$ to be compared to the solution obtained by Newton method is
$x=\color{red}{26.20165628306386}$

Even for $c=1$, the above truncated series gives $x=1.93317$ to bee compared to the solution $x=1.93295$.

Reinjecting this expression in $(1)$, the difference between lhs and rhs is  $\frac{81479}{44800 e^{10} c^9} \sim \frac{8.25\times 10^{-5} } {c^9}$

Comment: @user619894. You are right. I shall fix it. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have to decide why you prefer a closed-form solution. Sometimes it's sufficient to give your solution a name and say that it is in closed form then. But if you want to calculate with your closed-form solutions or wants to compare them, you need the methods for calculating in your set of closed-form functions/numbers.
Finding a solution in closed form means you get hints about series presentations, calculation rules, properties etc.

You have to decide which kinds of constants, operations/functions and variables you want to accept to be allowed to call it in [closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression). Simple classes of expressions e.g. are radical expressions (explicit algebraic expressions) or [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function).
Further classes of functions could be e.g. the [algebraic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_function), Lambert W, generalizations of Lambert W (e.g. as the previous answer suggests), special standard functions, hypergeometric functions, generalized hypergeometric functions.

You can decide to stop if you have checked all known classes of functions.

Comment: If a function appears only in a few papers, is it still a closed form or should it be considered one when it is implemented into other softwares/ part of other sources?

Comment: @TymaGaidash If we define the term "closed form" mathematically, it's sufficient to give the mathematically closed-form object a name. Preferably, some properties are also described. But you can add your answer with the practical aspects.